# css inline rotation

Tags: css

I have a table. In my td I have 2 li. In the first li I have 2 `<p>`. The first `<p>` represents the day and the second one the month. I would like to rotate by 90 degrees the second `<p>`, and I would like it to be displayed next to the day. My code is not working if I put `display:inline` on `<p>`. If I remove `display:inline` the rotation is working great but the 2 `<p>`s are not displayed next to each other but one below each other. And this is not what I would like. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Here my HTML:

```
<td>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>12</p>
      <p>FEB</p>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

My CSS:

```
#div td li p{
    display:inline;
    font-size:10px;}

#div td li p:last-child{
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p>12</p>
                    <p>FEB</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


td li p{
    display:inline-block;
    /* for lte IE7 */
    #zoom: 1
    #display: inline;
    font-size:10px;
}

td li p:last-child{
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to first sort out your HTML usage. This is not the correct way to use unordered lists `<ul>` or paragraphs `<p>`. You are displaying neither a paragraph or a list, just a date. There were also syntax errors in your css [missing semi-colon, #div means id="div" in HTML which is not correct]

Here is your problem resolved. I striped out the `<ul>` and the `<p>` and just used a `<span>`. Then I added a class to that span of 'side'. This class then has the rotation values you set.

http://cssdesk.com/U8ZRy

Comment: Hello iiz. Thanks for helping. I am building a calendar. In each td I want to display the date and below some info. That is the reason why I am using a list with 2 li inside my td. I didn't posted all the html for more clarity. In addition I don't get what you are saying regarding the semicolumn. My div id is div. I gave that name again for clarity purpose. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry for the #div assumption, and actually I cannot find the semi-colon problem again so maybe I deleted it myself! But I do maintain that the HTML could be cleaned up for semantic and practical reasons:

In a calendar I don't think the date and its entry are related in the way a list suggests; I would try to put the date outside of a list of entries. And two the elements of the date day and month do not constitute different paragraphs of information, hence my '<span>' suggestion.

Comment: I will take your suggestions into consideration. By the way, I discovered CSSDesk thanks to you. It is a good addition to Fiddle. Thanks!